# Determine if file exists

Tags: excel, vba

I want to open workbook up to variable in the archive list.

If I don't have the file in the archive, I want it to show a message box, but it did not work.

```
strVariable = Left(PictureNo, 4)
d = "Teknik Resim Arsiv Listesi_" & strVariable & ".xls"
Dim Ret
Ret = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & d)

If Ret = False Then
    MsgBox "Not Found"
End If
```

Comment: Have a look at `DIR` functionality in VBA. You can use that to identify if the file exists or not before you attempt to open the file

Answer (score 1):

Check for the existence of the file **before** attempting to open it:

```
strVariable = Left(PictureNo, 4)
d = "Teknik Resim Arsiv Listesi_" & strVariable & ".xls"
If Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & d) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Not Found"
Else
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & d)
End If
```